# K&R Exercise 1-13. Printing histogram of word lengths (horizontal variant)

Tags: beginner, c, io, ascii-art, data-visualization

I'm going through the K&R book (2nd edition, ANSI C ver.) and want to get the most from it. How does the following solution look to you? Note that, for the sake of exercise, I don't want to use techniques not introduced yet in the book. Also, I'm trying to reuse whatever code/philosophy already presented in the book.

```
/* Exercise 1-13. Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in
 * its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal; a vertical
 * orientation is more challenging.
 * */
/* Solution 1: Horizontal Bars
 * */
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN  10  /* Any word longer than this will get counted in the >MAXLEN histogram.
                     * For output formatting, the program assumes this won't be greater than 999.
                     * */
#define IN      1   /* inside a word */
#define OUT     0   /* outside a word */

int main()
{
    int c, state;
    int i, j;
    int histo[MAXLEN+1];
    int counter;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLEN+1; ++i)
        histo[i] = 0;

    /* Perform the counting */
    state = OUT;
    counter = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            if (state == IN && counter > 0) {
                if (counter-1 < MAXLEN)
                    ++histo[counter-1];
                else
                    ++histo[MAXLEN];
            }
            state = OUT;
            counter = 0;
        }
        else {
            ++counter;
            if (state == OUT)
                state = IN;
        }

    /* Print horizontal histogram. I'd use a function for formatting
     * with regards to max. number of digits, but functions haven't
     * been introduced yet.
     * */
    for (i = 0; i < MAXLEN; ++i) {
        if (MAXLEN < 10)
            printf(" %1d | ", i+1);
        else if (MAXLEN < 100)
            printf(" %2d |", i+1);
        else
            printf(" %3d |", i+1);
        for (j = 0; j < histo[i]; ++j)
            putchar('*');
        putchar('\n');
    }
    if (MAXLEN < 10)
        printf(">%1d |", i);
    else if (MAXLEN < 100)
        printf(">%2d |", i);
    else
        printf(">%3d |", i);
    for (j = 0; j < histo[i]; ++j)
        putchar('*');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Output when run on the program code:

```
$ cat ch1-ex-1-13-01.c | ./ch1-ex-1-13-01
  1 |*********************************************************
  2 |****************************************************************
  3 |***************************************
  4 |************************************
  5 |**************
  6 |**********
  7 |************************
  8 |***********
  9 |*******
 10 |*********
>10 |**************
```

Comment: By the way, which Version of the C Standard are you targeting? Premordial, K&R, C90, C99, C11?

Comment: I didn't think about it until I saw the answer here using C99 & C90. I guess I'll be sticking to K&R 2nd edition as I go through the book, but it certainly wouldn't hurt to be aware of new features where relevant.

Comment: I earnestly suggest that you take a close look at your book: Is it really K&R-C, or (mostly) C90? It depends on the revision. In any case, I suggest targeting at least C90, which might be ancient but is still ubiquitous. For Background, consider reading [this post on meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365267/is-kernighan-and-ritchie-a-valid-tag-on-stack-overflow) and [this tag-wiki on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kernighan-and-ritchie/info).

Comment: Since it's 2nd ed. I interpret it as being C90, right? `The second edition, "K&R2", was first published in 1988 with some updates of the book to meet the version of the language standardized by ANSI in 1989.` and `The 1989 ANSI C standard was republished by ISO in 1990`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K&R C requires all variables to be declared at the start of their enclosing block.  This is a bad habit to learn: it's much safer to declare variables where they can be initialised:

```
/* these can already be initialised where they are declared */
int state = OUT;
int histo[MAXLEN+1] = { 0 };  /* C90 */
int counter = 0;
```

```
/* reduce scope, and never have uninitialized value */
for (int j = 0; j < histo[i]; ++j)  /* C99 */
```

---

We could remove the need to subtract 1 from the length when updating `histo` if we reserve the first element for long words instead of the last:

```
        if (state == IN && counter > 0) {
            if (counter <= MAXLEN)
                ++histo[counter];
            else
                ++histo[0];
        }
```

We obviously need to make a corresponding change to the printing:

```
for (int i = 1;  i <= MAXLEN;  ++i) {
    if (MAXLEN < 10)
        printf(" %1d | ", i);
    else if (MAXLEN < 100)
        printf(" %2d |", i);
    else
        printf(" %3d |", i);
    for (int j = 0;  j < histo[i];  ++j)
        putchar('*');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

---

We can avoid the `if`/`else` chain on `MAXLEN` in this loop, by choosing the formatting string in advance:

```
const char *format = "";
if (MAXLEN < 10) {
        format = " %1d | ";
} else if (MAXLEN < 100) {
        format = " %2d | ";
}  else {
        format = " %3d | ";
}

for (int i = 1;  i <= MAXLEN;  ++i) {
    printf(format, i);
    for (int j = 0;  j < histo[i];  ++j)
        putchar('*');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

That might not look like an improvement, but with a small change, we can use the same format string to insert `>` for the over-long words, too:

```
const char *format = "";
if (MAXLEN < 10) {
        format = "%c%1d | ";
} else if (MAXLEN < 100) {
        format = "%c%2d | ";
}  else {
        format = "%c%3d | ";
}

for (int i = 1;  i <= MAXLEN;  ++i) {
    printf(format, ' ', i);
    for (int j = 0;  j < histo[i];  ++j)
        putchar('*');
    putchar('\n');
}

/* over-long words */
printf(format, '>', MAXLEN);
for (int j = 0; j < histo[0]; ++j)
    putchar('*');
putchar('\n');
```

Going beyond the expected level of knowledge, we could even compute the necessary length, and pass it using `%*d`:

```
int width = 1;
for (int i = MAXLEN;  i >= 10;  i /= 10) {
    ++width;
}

for (int i = 1;  i <= MAXLEN;  ++i) {
    printf(" %*d | ", width, i);
    for (int j = 0;  j < histo[i];  ++j)
        putchar('*');
    putchar('\n');
}

/* over-long words */
printf(">%*d | ", width, MAXLEN);
for (int j = 0; j < histo[0]; ++j)
    putchar('*');
putchar('\n');
```

That allows us to have non-constant `MAXLEN`, which will be to our advantage in future when we make this a function.

---

Whilst the state machine is a good idea, it turns out we don't need to explicitly store `state`, because `counter` is always zero outside a word and non-zero once we're in one:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
        if (counter > 0) {
            ++histo[counter <= MAXLEN ? counter : 0];
            counter = 0;
        }
    } else {
        ++counter;
    }
}
```

---

Did you spot the bug in this loop?  Probably not, because the bug is missing code *immediately after* the loop.  If the input stream ends during a word, we fail to count it.  We need to repeat the `if (counter > 0)` test just after the loop, to catch that case.

---

We have an unusual definition of "word" - in our source code, strings such as `++histo[counter-1];` count as single words.  Even in English text, we'd expect `text,` to register as a four-character word.  To fix this, we could consider only alphanumerics as word characters, and that could be a good introduction to the functions in `<ctype.h>`.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (isalnum(c)) {
        ++counter;
    } else {
        if (counter > 0) {
            ++histo[counter <= MAXLEN ? counter : 0];
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}

if (counter > 0) {
    ++histo[counter <= MAXLEN ? counter : 0];
}
```

---

Enhancement - we could avoid bars going off the right edge of the display, by calculating a scale factor first.  Here's my suggestion:

```
#define MAXWIDTH 72             /* screen width available for bars */
```

```
    double scale = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0;  i <= MAXLEN;  ++i) {
        if (histo[i] * scale > MAXWIDTH) {
            scale = 1.0 * MAXWIDTH / histo[i];
        }
    }
```

```
        for (int j = 0;  j < histo[i] * scale;  ++j) { putchar('*'); }
```

---

Finally: it's not part of your C code, but there's no need for `cat` in the test.  We can simply redirect input like this:

```sh
./ch1-ex-1-13-01 <ch1-ex-1-13-01.c
```

---

## Modified code

Applying all my suggestions, I got:

```
/* Exercise 1-13. Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of
   words in its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars
   horizontal; a vertical orientation is more challenging. */

/* Solution 1: Horizontal Bars
 * */
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN  10  /* Any word longer than this will get counted in the
                       >MAXLEN histogram. */

#define MAXWIDTH 72             /* screen width available for bars */

int main()
{
    int histo[MAXLEN+1] = { 0 }; /* element 0 counts over-length words */

    /* Perform the counting */
    int counter = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isalnum(c)) {
            ++counter;
        } else {
            if (counter > 0) {
                ++histo[counter <= MAXLEN ? counter : 0];
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (counter > 0) {
        ++histo[counter <= MAXLEN ? counter : 0];
    }

    /* Calculate sensible scale */
    double scale = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0;  i <= MAXLEN;  ++i) {
        if (histo[i] * scale > MAXWIDTH) {
            scale = 1.0 * MAXWIDTH / histo[i];
        }
    }

    /* how wide are the labels? */
    int width = 1;
    for (int i = MAXLEN;  i >= 10;  i /= 10) {
        ++width;
    }

    /* Write the output */
    for (int i = 1;  i <= MAXLEN;  ++i) {
        printf(" %*d | ", width, i);
        for (int j = 0;  j < histo[i] * scale;  ++j) { putchar('*'); }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    /* over-long words */
    printf(">%*d | ", width, MAXLEN);
    for (int j = 0; j < histo[0] * scale; ++j) { putchar('*'); }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Wow, great, thank you! Is your array initialization also C99? I thought about using [0] for the over-length but wasn't sure if it's good for code readability. I do like it, tho. Cool idea for formatting string with the `%c%d`, I'll remember that (char array assignment hasn't been introduced yet, tho). Didn't know about the `%*d` trick, I'd probably go with `sprintf` instead. `/=` hasn't been introduced, but I get the idea. For the bug, nice catch, I didn't notice. Or, we could say we're counting **complete** words :) As for word definition, I agree tho I followed the book example 1.5.4 there.

Comment: That initialization is plain C90 (C99 adds support for non-constant initializers, but incomplete initializer lists go back to at least the first Standard C).  The use of element `[0]` is clearer in my (subjective) opinion, but others may differ (or might want more comments).  As for the rest, I don't have my K&R with me here, so had to guess what's in scope and what's not!

Comment: Nice to know, I'm yet to learn about different standards. For now I'm just following K&R as if we're still living in the 80's. I've implemented your comments myself and posted it as another answer. Fixed some scaling issues, too.

Comment: If the number of stars is bounded and acceptably small, they can all be printed at once using part of the same string-literal. And that can be fused with the preceding `printf()` and trailing printing of a newline.

Comment: Yes @Deduplicator, that's probably what I'd do with this.  I was already in too deep, though...

Answer (score 0):

## Take 2

I've reworked my code according to the comments received [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/205680/181968) but sticking to the techniques which have been introduced up to this point in K&R, which means the following is NOT used:

- variable declaration where first initialized,
- assignment of char array constants,
- %*d format specifier,
- ctype.h.

Some other improvements:

- avoided repeating some code by introducting `readEOF` state,
- improved scaling,
- check whether MAXWIDTH is sufficient to print the smallest possible chart,
- printing numerical value next to histogram,
- figured out how to print labels better, while sticking to the techniques introduced so far,
- limited source code width to 72,
- fixed a scaling bug due to flating point precision,
- reverted to storing >MAXLEN count in the last element.

#### Modified code

```
/* Exercise 1-13. Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of
 * words in its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars
 * horizontal; a vertical orientation is more challenging.
 * */
/* Solution 1: Horizontal Bars
 * Take 2: Implementing some comments received from SE:
 * https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205674#205680
 * but sticking to the techniques which have been introduced up to this
 * point in K&R, which means the following is NOT used:
 *      - variable declaration where first initialized,
 *      - assignment of char array constants,
 *      - %*d format specifier,
 *      - <ctype.h>.
 * Some other improvements:
 *      - avoided repeating some code by introducing `readEOF` state,
 *      - improved scaling,
 *      - check whether MAXWIDTH is sufficient to print the smallest
 *          possible chart,
 *      - printing numerical value next to histogram,
 *      - figured out how to print labels better, while sticking to the
 *          techniques introduced so far,
 *      - limited source code width to 72,
 *      - fixed a scaling bug due to flating point precision,
 *      - reverted to storing >MAXLEN count in the last element.
 * */
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN      10  /* Any word longer than this will get counted in
                         * the >MAXLEN histogram. */
#define MAXWIDTH    72  /* Max. width for chart printout, the whole
                         * chart will be scaled to fit. */

int main()
{
    int c;
    int i, j;
    int histogram[MAXLEN+1]; /* last element will count the over-length
                              * words */
    int alnumCount;
    int readEOF;
    int labelW;
    int maxLabelW;
    int maxWordCount;
    int maxWordCountW;
    float scale;

    for (i = 0; i <= MAXLEN; ++i)
        histogram[i] = 0;

    /* Perform the counting */
    alnumCount = 0;
    readEOF = 0;
    c = getchar();
    while (readEOF == 0) {
        if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || 
            (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ||
            (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
            ++alnumCount;
        else {
            if (alnumCount > 0) {
                if (alnumCount <= MAXLEN)
                    ++histogram[alnumCount-1];
                else
                    ++histogram[MAXLEN];
                alnumCount = 0;
            }
        }
        if ((readEOF = (c == EOF)) == 0)
            c = getchar();
    }

    /* Chart Printing Section
     * */
    /* Each histogram will look like:
     * ">NNN |******************** MMM",
     * showing both the label and the histogram value, so we can display
     * accurate information even if the chart is scaled.
     * To be able to plot on a fixed screen width, we must calculate the
     * max. histogram value, the widths of NNN & MMM fields, and finally
     * the scale.
     * */

    /* Find max. histogram value */
    maxWordCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= MAXLEN; ++i) 
        if (maxWordCount < histogram[i])
            maxWordCount = histogram[i];

    /* Calculate histogram value max. width */
    maxWordCountW = 1;
    for (i = maxWordCount;  i >= 10;  i = i/10)
        ++maxWordCountW;

    /* Calculate label max. width */
    maxLabelW = 1;
    for (i = MAXLEN;  i >= 10;  i = i/10)
        ++maxLabelW;

    /* Calculate the scale */
    /* Note - histogram layout: ">NNN |******************** MMM". */
    scale = 1.0*(MAXWIDTH - 1 - maxLabelW - 2 - 1 - maxWordCountW) / 
            maxWordCount;

    /* Fix a scale rounding bug */
    if (scale * maxWordCount < MAXWIDTH - 1 - maxLabelW - 2 - 1 - 
        maxWordCountW)
        scale = scale + 0.000001;

    /* Print the chart only if MAXWIDTH is sufficient to print at least
     * the values */
    if (maxWordCount * scale >= 0)
        /* Print horizontal histogram. */
        /* Row loop */
        for (i = 0; i <= MAXLEN; ++i) {
            /* Print either the " " or ">" for the last histogram */
            if (i < MAXLEN)
                putchar(' ');
            else
                putchar('>');

            /* Calculate the label width */
            labelW = 1;
            for (j = i+1;  j >= 10;  j = j/10)
                ++labelW;

            /* Print blanks as required for lavel alignment and print
             * the label */
            for (j = maxLabelW - labelW; j > 0; --j)
                putchar(' ');
            if (i < MAXLEN)
                printf("%d |", i+1);
            else
                printf("%d |", MAXLEN);

            /* Column loop, print the histogram */
            for (j = 1; j <= scale*histogram[i]; ++j)
                putchar('*');

            /* Print the histogram value */
            printf(" %d", histogram[i]);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    else
        printf("Error: insufficient screen width for print-out.\n");
}
```

#### Output when run on the program code

```
$ ./ch1-ex-1-13-01_Take2 < ch1-ex-1-13-01_Take2.c
  1 |*************************************************************** 103
  2 |*************************************** 64
  3 |************************************************* 81
  4 |***************************** 49
  5 |********************************************* 74
  6 |************************** 43
  7 |****************** 31
  8 |************** 24
  9 |************************* 41
 10 |*********** 18
>10 |************** 23
```

Comment: If you want to get that reviewed, make it a new question.

Comment: Didn't intend to go through round 2, just posting here [for info](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c). I'll post the vertical variant as a new Q once I'm done with it.